# Need Help figuring out last part of python script

Tags: python, bash

I have attempted to write the code to produce the following output... however I have a question about the end of the code which will output the number of digits in the value which I figured out but how does the value of that number of digits output as words such as 
Value: 23575
There are 2 fives in the value

but with the code I've attempted it outputs
Enter a number: 23575
       Value: 23575
Number of digits: 5
   Sum of digits: 22
{2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 2, 7: 1}
There is 1 2 in the value
There is 1 3 in the value
**There are 2 5s in the value**
There is 1 7 in the value

or 
 Value: 1834
There is 1 four in the value

Writing a script that will produce the following output:
(python or bash)
1.) the input value that was provided
2.) the number of digits in the value
3.) the sum of the individual digits in the value
this is the part I couldn't figure out 4.) the number of times the answer from #2 occurs in the value
 and I haven't how to do this ~~>The script should allow for input of one or more integers, looping until a zero is entered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omggd.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not there to do your homework, but to give answers to clearly stated, specific questions. As it is, your question is hard to understand. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (esp. the sections about homework) and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's my approach for your exercise. My approach was to convert the given number into a string, so that the function can easily count the number of digits - I didn't use any libraries of course.

```py
(...)
```

EDIT: Seems like I misunderstood your question regarding the last path. Here is the correct solution you need:

```py
def number_of_occurences(value, searched_digit):
    count = 0
    for digit in str(value):
        if int(digit) == searched_digit:
            count = count + 1
    print(f"Times {searched_digit} appear in {value}: {count}")

def get_unique_digits(value): 
    unique_list = list()
    for digit in str(value):
        if int(digit) not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(int(digit))
    print(f"Unique digits in list: {unique_list}")
    return unique_list        

def count_all_sums(value, digits): 
    for digit in digits: 
        number_of_occurences(value, digit)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    count_all_sums(132323232323, get_unique_digits(132323232323))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a n2s=(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine)
# map numbers to strings

while true; do
    read -p "Enter a number: " value            # prompt for the value
    value="$( sed 's/^0\+//' <<< "$value" )"    # remove leading zeros

    if [[ -n ${value//[0-9]/} ]]; then          # non-digit character is entered
        echo "Enter only digits."
        continue
    elif (( value == 0 )); then                 # 0 is entered then quit
        echo "Bye."
        exit
    fi

    length="${#value}"                          # number of digits
    unset sum count                             # initialize variables
    for (( i=0; i<length; i++ )); do
        digit="${value:$i:1}"                   # i'th digit from left
        (( count[digit]++ ))                    # increment the counter
        (( sum+=digit ))                        # accumulate the sum
    done

    # report the results
    printf "Value: %d\n" "$value"
    printf "Number of digits: %d\n" "$length"
    printf "Sum of digits: %d\n" "$sum"
    for i in {0..9}; do
        if (( count[i] == 1 )); then
            printf "There is %d %s in the value\n" "${count[$i]}" "${n2s[$i]}"
        elif (( count[i] > 1 )); then
            printf "There are %d %ss in the value\n" "${count[$i]}" "${n2s[$i]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

The puzzling problem will be how to break the entered value into individual
digits. You can make use of `substring expansion` of `bash` denoted by
`${parameter:offset:length}`. For example, the expression `{$str:2:1}`
returns the substring of `$str` starting at 2 and of length 1. You can
extract individual digits with a loop by incrementing the starting position
from 0 to length - 1.
Hope this helps.